# MongoDB not uses indexes on some fields when doing distinct

Tags: mongodb, indexing, distinct

I have noticed that MongoDB won't use indexes when querying for a distinct value on a field. I will use it on some fields, but won't on others.

Here's the example:

```
db.product.createIndex({"_indexed.preventieve_mondzorg-max_bedrag_p_jr": 1});
db.runCommand({distinct: "product", key:"_indexed.preventieve_mondzorg-max_bedrag_p_jr"});
```

This query will not use an index that is built on that field and will go for the full collection scan. That's what it produces:

```
{
    "createdCollectionAutomatically" : false,
    "numIndexesBefore" : 50,
    "numIndexesAfter" : 50,
    "note" : "all indexes already exist",
    "ok" : 1
}
{
    "values" : [
        "&euro; 250,- | 75%",
        "Geen dekking",
        "...",
    ],
    "stats" : {
        "n" : 33660,
        "nscanned" : 0,
        "nscannedObjects" : 33660,
        "timems" : 12531,
        "planSummary" : "COLLSCAN"
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

On the other hand

```
db.product.createIndex({"free_choice.value": 1});
db.runCommand({distinct: "product", key:"free_choice.value"});
```

Will the index:

```
{
    "createdCollectionAutomatically" : false,
    "numIndexesBefore" : 50,
    "numIndexesAfter" : 50,
    "note" : "all indexes already exist",
    "ok" : 1
}
{
    "values" : [
        "gedeeltelijk",
        "geen",
        "ja"
    ],
    "stats" : {
        "n" : 4,
        "nscanned" : 4,
        "nscannedObjects" : 4,
        "timems" : 2,
        "planSummary" : "DISTINCT { free_choice.value: 1.0 }"
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

So... what could be the difference between those two fields?

Is it a bug, or I am doing something wrong?

I am running MongoDB 3.0.6 in a Vagrant box with Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is the bug of MongoDB core. Or misbehaviour.  MongoDB would not use multikey index for dotted fields for distinct requests.

Here's the Mongo's response:

> The distinct optimization uses a special index access stage which
>   returns the distinct index keys to its parent stage. In the multikey
>   dotted case, however, the distinct stage would have to check for null
>   or undefined keys. In the case of null or undefined, it must fetch the
>   full document in order to disambiguate between literal nulls versus
>   null by virtue of missing fields. We have decided to hold off unless
>   we see that users really need this.

If you really want this feature, please vote for it here: [SERVER-13298](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-13298)